# Register a customer via ajax in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I need a code to register a customer via ajax in magento 2 , If any body have any samples please share

thanks

Answer (score 0):

After an full day of research, I found this answer over the Internet, which solved my problem:

```
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$url = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $url->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$mediaurl= $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
// Customer Factory to Create Customer
$customerFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');
$websiteId = $storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
/// Get Store ID
$store = $storeManager->getStore();
$storeId = $store->getStoreId();

// Instantiate object (this is the most important part)
$customer = $customerFactory->create();
$customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);

// Preparing data for new customer
$customer->setEmail("EXAMPLE@gmail.com");
$customer->setFirstname("EXAMPLE");
$customer->setLastname("EXAMPLE");
$customer->setPassword("admin@123");

try{
    // Save data
    $customer->save();
    echo 'Succesfully Saved'.$customer->getId();
    // Add Address For created customer
    $addresss = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory');
    $address = $addresss->create();

    $address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
            ->setFirstname('EXAMPLE')
            ->setLastname('EXAMPLE')
            ->setCountryId('IN')
            //->setRegionId('1') //state/province, only needed if the country is USA
            ->setPostcode('31000')
            ->setCity('EXAMPLE')
            ->setTelephone('00000000000')
            ->setFax('0000000000')
            ->setCompany('GMI')
            ->setStreet('EXAMPLE')
            ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
            ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
            ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
    try{
        $address->save();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
    }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}
```